# Android + Marshmallow 6.0 : How to clear cache of app on Android?

Tags: mobile, android

I am testing an App on Marshmallow Android. Observed a few weird behaviors. To confirm I wanted to find the exact steps to reproduce the issue. I am trying to clear the cache on Android version 6.0 i.e. Marshmallow

How can I clear the cache of the App particularly on Android Marshmallow?

Comment: http://www.androidauthority.com/android-6-0-marshmallow-how-to-clear-app-data-and-cache-647355/

Comment: Super. Its easy with screenshots. Can you add in answer?

Comment: Sure thing. Glad to help!

Comment: yea but how do you do it for just a single app????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to clear app data and cache in Android 6.0 Marshmallow](http://www.androidauthority.com/android-6-0-marshmallow-how-to-clear-app-data-and-cache-647355/) is slightly different from prior versions of Android:

1. Open the Settings menu either through your notification shade (drop-down) or through the Settings app in your app drawer.
2. Navigate down to “Apps”. This may be renamed to something like Applications or Application Manager in OEM skinned versions of Android 6.0.
3. Once in there, click on an application.
4. You’ll now see a list of stuff that gives you information about the app, including Storage, Permissions, Memory Use, and more. These are all clickable items. You’ll want to click on Storage.
5. You should now clearly see the Clear Data and Clear Cache buttons for the application.

Done!
[image]
Reference:
http://www.androidauthority.com/android-6-0-marshmallow-how-to-clear-app-data-and-cache-647355/